# Excel formula error

Tags: excel

I am currently trying to SUM a cost value against certain criteria in excel - My formula below keeps saying "too many arguments" or is just not working. I also need this table in a separate sheet.

```
=COUNTIFS(Diversey!A:A,"1",Diversey!I:I,"CUST: POD signed unchecked",Diversey!M:M)
```

The "1" represents the week number,
The "CUST: POD signed unchecked" is the criteria that I want to calculate the cost value against and in Column M is where I want to sum the Value.

IFSUM-one can help me and tell me what I am doing wrong!!

Comment: **Count** ifs is not **Sum** ifs. Maybe `=SUMIFS(Diversey!M:M,Diversey!A:A,"1",Diversey!I:I,"CUST: POD signed unchecked")` is what you want? [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

Comment: It works - I actually love you right now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I just need to ask you one more thing.

Comment: So I need the formula not to count if column N displays "N/A" - is this possible?

Comment: Would this make sense - =COUNTIFS(Diversey!A:A,"1",Diversey!H:H,"127",Diversey!Y:Y,"Warehouse" or "Transport") Column Y has a list that I can select either Warehouse, Transport or N/A. Because I haven't included N/A in the formula, would this mean it won't count if N/A displayed in column Y?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Diversey!A:A,"1",Diversey!I:I,"CUST: POD signed unchecked",Diversey!M:M)
```

has 5 parameters instead 6.

Because you must to write a couple of paramter for every range (the first is criteria range, the second is criteria and so on for each range)

If you go [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) you can read the **Remarks** section.

**EDIT**

- 1st couple: Diversey!A:A, "1"
- 2nd couple: Diversey!I:I,"CUST: POD signed unchecked"
- 3rd couple: Diversey!M:M **<-- TO COMPLETE**

Comment: Thank you for your help - I understand why this is throwing up an error but I can't seem to amend the code for it to work!!